# Why do variables become keys on the window object?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that variables become keys and their values become values of said keys when I am writing on the window object.  For instance:

```
var variable = "value";
console.log(window.variable);//logs "value"
```

But if I create a new object of my own like:

```
var o = {
    key: "value",
    var key2 = "value2"
}; // result: "syntax error"
```

I have to use the colon to set key/value pairs.  And even with constructor functions, although I don't get a syntax error, I don't seem to be able to do this inside the constructor function or during object instantiation or after:

```
function Blueprint(){
    this.key = "value";
    var key2 = "value2";
}

var o = new Blueprint;
console.log(o.key); //result: "value"
console.log(o.key2); //result: "undefined"
```

Now, I understand why, in the former case, I generated a syntax error and why in the latter case I was unable to attach key2 to the Blueprint constructor function but what I don't understand why on the global window object I am given free range to just add properties using variables and they instantly become keys on the window object.  Other than on the windows object, variables seem to behave as though they are independent of objects and property creation.

I've also noticed similar behavior on the global object when experimenting with node.  Are global objects the only objects that can set key/value pairs in this way using variables?  And if so, why?  Why aren't we forced to do something like the following when working on the global level:

```
this.key = "value";
```

Or...

```
window.key = "value";
```

Is this just some caveat to the behavior of the language overall or is there some internally consistent logic about the window object in relation to all other objects that explains this?

Comment: It's magic. See https://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3

Comment: Every variable scope has an object that holds variables. It just so happens that in the global scope we have direct access to that object.

Comment: ...it's sort of similar to the `arguments` object in a function. You pass arguments to parameters, and they're accessible via the paramter identifiers, but there's this object that automatically appears that also holds the values you passed. Change the parameter value and it changes on the `arguments` object and vice versa *(though this persistent mapping doesn't exist in strict mode)*.

Answer (score 4):

Global variables (as opposed to local variables declared within a function) become properties of the global object.

In a browser, the global object is `window`.

Comment: SLaks, thank you for your response, but my question was not whether this happens (it's quite obvious that this happens) my question was WHY this happens.  Is there some internal reason for this change in behavior or is it just a language caveat.  Thank you very much anyway, I appreciate your input.

Comment: @AllanSocks: Read the spec.

Answer (score 2):

The global environment is a so called [*Object Environment (Record)*](https://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.2):

> Each object environment record is associated with an object called its binding object. An object environment record binds the set of identifier names that directly correspond to the property names of its binding object.

As you can see, the behavior to create properties for identifiers is explicitly defined. And in the case of the global environment, the binding object is the global object, which is `window` in browsers.

More detailed information about environments can be found in the [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x10.2):

> There are two kinds of Environment Record values used in this specification: *declarative environment records* and *object environment records*. Declarative environment records are used to define the effect of ECMAScript language syntactic elements such as *FunctionDeclarations*, *VariableDeclarations*, and *Catch* clauses that directly associate identifier bindings with ECMAScript language values. Object environment records are used to define the effect of ECMAScript elements such as *Program* and *WithStatement* that associate identifier bindings with the properties of some object.

I can't tell you *why* these two types exist. If you want to know that, you could ask at http://esdiscuss.org/